# Convert .csv to Excel file and email as attachment

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to convert a .csv file to Excel using unix shell script. Tried replacing pipe delimited to comma separated using the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /main/subpath/dev/Int/Source/adm/at/csv_xls
for f in *.csv; do 
sed 's/^\||/,/g' "$f" > "${f%.csv}.xls"
done
ls *.csv;
echo "CSV Excel Con" | mailx -s "Testing CSV2Excel" -a "${f%.csv}.xls" jennny@gmail.com
```

I have multiple Excel files. I need to send all the Excel files as email attachments. When I tried using this script it is attaching only one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [ssconvert](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssconvert)

```
ssconvert file1.csv file1.xlsx
```

Comment: Should I install any library for this script to work. I tried this script already but it says - command not found.

Comment: If it's not already installed you can install it with `sudo apt install gnumeric`

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response and guidance.